Unresponsive domain names freeze SSH connection when using SOCKS proxy
Is it possible to stop the SSH connection freezing when using dynamic port forwarding (SOCKS proxy) when it encounters an unresponsive DNS name?
I found the whole SSH connection freezes when going on ebay.co.uk with connect failed: Temporary failure in name resolution printed several times in the terminal and the only way to get it working again is to kill the ssh process and restart it. I narrowed it down to ebay.entmag.co.uk causing the freeze and get Temporary failure in name resolution when pinging it.

I have asked the SSH experts and they said this isn't a simple fix so this is a big blow to my project. Shame.
